# Why no automatic level progression in Resident Evil Revelations

Tags: resident-evil-revelations

I've just started raid mode in RE: Revelations (DS) and I noticed that that the games doesn't automatically level up your character when you have enough XP(?) to do so. Obviously some weapons have a minimum level requirement, but is there an advantage to keeping your character at a lower level?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you stick at level 1 regardless of your overall level progression. As soon as you switch over to a higher level it will automatically change, as you would expect it to normally. So why have the option to play a lower level? The trinity bonus:

And for that you need:
1 - Be the same level (or lower) as the stage you playing
2 - Kill ALL enemies on the stage
3 - Not get hit by enemies, not even a little bit

Complete all three of these and you will be awarded the trinity bonus!